# Azure AD B2C user flows throws "Access ... has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PATCH is not allowed..." when saving "Access tokens(implicit flow)"

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

In my Azure AD B2C, I created an application to implement user flows.
Unfortunately when I try to "run user flow" the token I get is incorrect and cannot be decoded.
I read that to solve that I have to mark "Access tokens (used for implicit flows)" but when I clicked the "save" button I got a CORS issue as on the below screen.
How can I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the reason.
It was because of Chrome extension: Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
When removed it the exception stopped occurring.